# TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined new Version

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

This problem was more common, but I changed the code accordingly the new version of v 1.0. ..
Normally the code would have to work according to the new version. But it does not and I ask why it could be

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {

  //const user_id = context.params.user_id;
  //const notification = context.params.notification_id;

  console.log('The User Id is : ',context.params.user_id);
});
```

This is the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:7:31)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
at next (native)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:716:24
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

And here is my Database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCzy2.png)

Why is the user_id still undefined ?

Comment: You are writing the exact same code as a bunch of people asking the same question on Stack Overflow.  Are you following some out-of-date tutorial or someting?

Comment: Check that you are running version 1.0.x of `firebase-functions` by looking in the `package.json` file in your project's functions folder.  If you need to update, follow the instructions in the [Getting Started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#build_the_sample_in_your_firebase_project).

Comment: @DougStevenson yes it's a part from a tutorial to make a chat app. The tutorial is from 2017 but I researched and changed my code accordingly to the new version but it still doesnt work

Comment: @BobSnyder yes the firebase-functions version is 1.0.3 and the firebase-admin version 5.12.1